# How to install RaspberryPIOS on WSL

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-desktop

I am trying to install Raspberry Pi OS on Windows subsystem for linux (WSL), but I do not know how to install it.
Could you tell me how to install it or tell me good homepage instructing installation?
Should I install Raspberry Pi OS  on WSL or WSL2?
Which OS should I install, the Raspberry Pi OS(for Raspberry device) or Debian with Raspberry Pi Desktop (Raspberry Pi Desktop for PC and Mac)?

Comment: This is not possible because Windows run on Intel x86 processor architecture and Raspberry OS is made for RPI arm CPU. Also the RPI has hardware which is completely different from what your Windows computer has. - You would need a complete RPI emulator in Windows - which I have not seen so far.

Comment: There is an x86(-64) version available: https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here.

Not sure if the answer to the posted question raises the correct point in answering why you can't run Raspian OS under WSL because the Raspberry Pi runs an ARM processor instead of an x86_64 Processor..

Since the release of Windows 10 on ARM 64-bit the issue of processor architecture differences (x86-64) vs
ARM64 seems moot.

That said, there could be two different paths to pursue to run an ARM64 based OS like Raspian 64 under WSL. The first would depend on how much support for the Raspian Linux kernel based OS is now available from the WSL running under Win 10 ARM64. Since Debian 64-bit (Buster) is the core of RASPIAN OS 64-bit and WSL now supports Debian 64-bit, a path forward appears open to port a Raspian OS 64-bit kernel to run as a WSL guest OS.

Alternatively, the Raspian OS drivers for the Pi 3B and the board device support to run it under WSL could be the next hurdle to overcome. Here, if QEMU is available on the Windows 10 ARM 64 platform, then there's an avenue to pursue to run the Raspian 64-bit OS using WSL with QEMU taking some of the board device burden.

Comment: I'd presume the OP is talking about this: https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/